# entryPoint "xxx" doesn't exist when add new entryPoint in Traefik 2.1.6

Tags: kubernetes

I am using traefik 2.1.6 as kuberentes ingress controller, now I want to add a new TCP entryPoint like this:

```
"containers": [
          {
            "name": "traefik-ingress-lb",
            "image": "traefik:2.1.6",
            "args": [
              "--configfile=/config/traefik.yaml",
              "--logLevel=INFO",
              "--metrics=true",
              "--metrics.prometheus=true",
              "--entryPoints.metrics.address=:8080",
              "--metrics.prometheus.entryPoint=metrics",
              "--metrics.prometheus.addServicesLabels=true",
              "--metrics.prometheus.addEntryPointsLabels=true",
              "--metrics.prometheus.buckets=0.100000, 0.300000, 1.200000, 5.000000",
              "--entryPoints.web.address=:80",
              "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443",
              "--entryPoints.xxljobmysql.address=:3308",
              "--certificatesResolvers.ali.acme.email=jiangtingqiang@gmail.com",
              "--certificatesResolvers.ali.acme.storage=/config/acme.json",
              "--certificatesResolvers.ali.acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=web",
              "--certificatesResolvers.ali.acme.httpChallenge=true",
              "--certificatesresolvers.ali.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
            ],
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "web",
                "hostPort": 80,
                "containerPort": 80,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "websecure",
                "hostPort": 443,
                "containerPort": 443,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "xxljobmysql",
                "hostPort": 3308,
                "containerPort": 3308,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "metrics",
                "containerPort": 8080,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
```

the `xxljobmysql` entryPoint is the new TCP entryPoint I wanted to add. But when I check on the Dashboard, It tell me:

```
entryPoint "xxljobmysql" doesn't exist
no valid entryPoint for this router
```

am I missing something and what should I do to fix it add make it work as expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traefik loading entrypoint config from configmap(`- '--configFile=/config/traefik.yaml'`), so just change the configmap like this:

```
serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true
api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true
  debug: true
metrics:
  prometheus: ""
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"
  websecure:
    address: ":443"
  hadesmysql:
    address: ":3311"
providers:
  kubernetesCRD: ""
log:
  filePath: ""
  level: error
  format: json
accessLog:
  filePath: ""
  format: json
  bufferingSize: 0
  filters:
    retryAttempts: true
    minDuration: 20
  fields:
    defaultMode: keep
    names:
      ClientUsername: drop
    headers:
      defaultMode: keep
      names:
        User-Agent: redact
        Authorization: drop
        Content-Type: keep
```

add the entrypoint in the file. do not modify in traefik yaml config:

```
 # this would not work
 - '--entryPoints.hadesmysql.address=:3311'
```